# Firefox navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia stream is correct on the first run, on the second run stream is broken and I cannot display video

Tags: javascript, firefox, video-streaming, navigator, mediadevices

I'm having trouble accessing the microphone and camera while using Firefox on windows after running this script on the second time. Chrome/edge is fine

```
      let stream;

      try {
        document.getElementById('record').onclick = async () => {
          stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true});
          document.getElementById('video').srcObject = stream;
        };
        document.getElementById('stop').onclick = () => {
          stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
          document.getElementById('video').srcObject = undefined;
          stream = null;
        };
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
```

On the second go stream seams to be legit, it contains video and audio track, but it won't display video correctly whereas chrome and safari deals with it without any issues. Should I treat firefox in a specific way? What could be wrong? I'll add that my camera & microphone is fine + I've granted the permissions

[fiddle link to the example code](https://jsfiddle.net/zqvfpjnx/11/)

Closing and reopening browser seam to make the issue go away, until I run that script again. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.  It's just that webcams tend to take a little extra time between when they're closed, and when they're re-opened.  It's a big issue for webcams that don't support multiple clients simultaneously.

I've experienced this problem occasionally on Chrome, as well as Firefox.

The best thing to do is handle errors and try again.